# library error management in c : different approaches

Tags: c, dll, error-handling

its first time that i'm developing something enough serious, so i have to manage errors. i have three approach in my mind that i can use :

```
COMDS_RETURN some_function(....)
```

the problem in this approach is that, sometime its easier to return a pointer to the 'data' for example a pointer to a linked list, but here if the function fail, i cannot know the cause why its has failed.

my second approach is to always append an 'error' argument:

```
pointer_to_data *some_function(...., error *myerror)
```

but here i will always add the overhead of additional argument in every function, and for some function returning the error is better like in the first approach.

well, and the third approach is to mix between the two first approaches, but again the problem here is that the library will not have a uniform calling/error checking model. for a function you must do it the first way, for another function you must do it the second way.

i want to know what is the best method between the three(or another one that exist).

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no "best" way; it depends on your use case, and each method has its pros and cons.

For example, COM objects typically return an `HRESULT` status value. If they need to return data to the user, they add an additional argument for a pointer to the data to write to. This has the advantage of being able to check the status inline with the call, i.e.

```
if (FAILED(d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(...)) {
    // handle failure...
}
```

Many functions in the C library have a special return value for indicating failure. Then, the user can reference `errno` for more information about the error. This has the benefit of not having to declare the data variables beforehand and passing them in as an extra argument.

Comment: `errno` is thread-safe (at least for linux/unix/posix, can't remember if the C standard mandates it).